# Using checkbox in virtual mode listview

Tags: delphi, listview, tcheckbox

I am learning to make virtual mode listview. So far my problem is I can not use checkbox in the listview. I already read a link from http://delphi-kb.blogspot.com/2011/02/draw-checkboxes-in-virtual-mode.html but I don't see any checkbox. Any idea?

Comment: BTW: Which Delphi version are you using? (I'm on D2007 here)

Comment: I use D2007 too for my program but I'm trying DXE2 now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you have to draw the CheckBoxes yourself when `OwnerData` is enabled (as mentioned in the article linked in the question).

So you have to set `OwnerDraw` to `True` (in addition to `OwnerData`, the two are **independed** flags!) and draw the CheckBoxes yourself in the `OnCustomDrawItem` event.

Update:

It seems that this is not entirely true, the `OnCustomDrawItem` event is also fired in the case `OwnerDraw = False`.

http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE2/en/ComCtrls.TListView.OnCustomDrawItem

Update 2:

The code linked in the question only works when `OwnerDraw = False` and `CheckBoxes = True`.

Otherwise the VCL doesn't reserve space on the left to draw CheckBoxes.

BTW: You might be better of using a more advanced component like TVirtualTreeView from Mike Lischke.

Comment: Jens, I have succeeded to use listview in virtual mode. I also have followed the instruction to add checkbox from link in my question and I still can't get the checkbox appear in the listview. Does the code from link above work for you?

Comment: It "works" when you I set CheckBoxes to True and OwnerDraw to False. If you don't the VCL will draw over the CheckBoxes and you won't see them.

Comment: From link above, what is `FileListMenu` in `DrawCheckMark(FileListMenu.ListView1, Item, Item.Checked);`? I just put this in my code `DrawCheckMark(ListView1, Item, Item.Checked);`.  Jens, I used to use TVirtualTree! but I am anticipating if I have to port my program to x64. Nobody guarantee TVirtualTree will be compatible with DXE2 x64. I make a simple demo that use code in link above, if you have another five minutes, please check. http://uploading.com/files/371emeb4/demo.zip/

Comment: Well the CheckBox is there, it is not drawn as checked. If you add `Item.Checked := True` to your `ListView1Data` it is drawn as Checked. So everything works as expected.

Comment: You can't change the CheckBox state by clicking on it though, if you want that behavior you'd have to write code for that yourself.

Comment: Aparently TVirtualTreevView is already being ported to XE2: http://code.google.com/p/virtual-treeview/source/list

Comment: Yeah they already ported it to XE2 for 32 bit version and I pray they will port it to 64 bit version :) I think I am going to switch back to use third party component for a while.